# Where in Brooklyn can I buy the round chasidish hat?

Tags: product-recommendation, clothing, chasidut-hasidism, head, black-hats

I'm referring to the hat that has the same finish as a normal fedora, just without the crease; not the flat hat with long fur that Satmarers wear or the higher flat ones. Like the one Rav Auerbach shlita is wearing.

[image]

Comment: I know the name but not the face. Which one is Rav Auerbacjh shlit'a, and who is the other shlit'a in the pic?

Comment: You ask in the title for a chassidesh hat, but Rav Aurbach is not chassidish.

Comment: @user6591, I am aware. I refer to it as a chasidish hat because it's associated primarily with chassidim just as rekels and shtreimels are. But some non-chasidim wear it too.

Comment: I'm not sure they are interchangeable. There may be sleight differences between them.

Comment: @user6591, possibly. Just like chabad and yeshivish hats have a different crease and look different. But they're both fedoras and are fundamentally the same hat. In this case however, I doubt it -- those in the Litvish olam who wear it are a minority, and are unlikely to have their own manufacturers. They simply dress like chasidim in most cases, and if the shtreimels and rekels are identical, it would stand to reason that the weekday hats are too.

Comment: A kappata is very different then a rekkel. If you think they are the same than you haven't noticed the differences. Closest hassidic hat might be a vishnitz one. Good luck.

Comment: No no, only Litvish rabbonim wear kapotes. Laymen who wear long coats (e.g., based on the Chazon Ish) are wearing rekels.

Comment: @DanF; Rav Auerbach shlita is on the right. The other is the Vizhnitzer Rebbe.

Comment: FYI the type of hat you are referring to is called a Homburg

Answer (score 2):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hasidic%20hat%20shop%20brooklyn&oq=hasidic+hat+shop+brooklyn&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.3575j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=40676268,-73968746,5119&tbm=lcl&rldimm=15982447541569637650&ved=0ahUKEwjctcHkpIzYAhVB7IMKHYVYBrcQvS4IUjAB&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:10#rlfi=hd:;si:15982447541569637650;mv:!1m3!1d45136.27528960343!2d-73.96874645!3d40.676268349999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i171!2i358!4f13.1;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:10) brings several results:

**Goorin Bros. Hat Shop**

181 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211

(718) 599-4287

**Ferster Hats**

5101 New Utrecht Ave #1, Brooklyn, NY 11219

(718) 854-6768

They even have a website (not listed on the Google entry) which you can see [here](http://www.fersterhats.com/home). You can take a look at the numerous hats they sell as well as order online.

On their website, you can see a number of [bent up hats](http://www.fersterhats.com/gallery/bent-up-hats) and also a selection of [more Chassidish hats](http://www.fersterhats.com/gallery/chasiddishe-hats).

**Primo Hatters**

366 Kingston Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11213

(718) 804-0770

Hope this helps. Somebody who actually lives in Brooklyn could tell you better.

Comment: I would be surprised if Primo had these.

Comment: There is a store called "Hat Box" on Coney Island Ave. and corner of either L or M. It's easy to spot because there's a giant hat on the roof of the building. I've never been inside, and I gather that they specialize in Borsalino "yeshivish" black hats. But, they may carry these as well.

Comment: @HodofHod I don't know if they do; I don't live in Brooklyn nor have I visited Primo Hatters personally.